# Adding python module to python path, afterwards importing it does fail, how come?

Tags: python

Okay, I have somewhere on a network drive a module which I want to use in my script (which is as well on the network drive).

I added that module to the python path:

```
new_path = '..\\..\\..\\ABC\\DEF\\1.0\\GHI'
new_path = os.path.realpath(new_path)
sys.path.append(new_path)
```

Afterwards I can see that it was proper added:

```
for p in sys.path:
   print p
```

But when I try to import it, it fails:

```
import GHI
```

The folder that contains GHI does have a `__init__.py` and I also tried to only put `'..\\..\\..\\ABC\\DEF\\1.0'` into the python path. This seems to be an easy failure, but I don't see it. :/

Comment: The module name GHI resides in folder ....\GHI?

Comment: It's always the same with those "relative path juggling", sometimes you just miss one level... I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the dir where the module resides to sys.path, not the path to the module (or module package dir) itself.

Try:

```
import os, pprint
new_path = os.path.abspath(r'..\..\..\ABC\DEF\1.0')
assert os.path.isdir(new_path), 'The dir does not exist!')
sys.path.append(new_path)
pprint sys.path
import GHI
```

Comment: Actually this was clear to me, but what helped was the check if the path exists... I had a typo! thanks a lot.